# [1, 1].map(&:*2)が動かないのはなぜ？

Tags: ruby

[1, 1].map(&:to_i)などはうまくいくんですが、
[1, 1].map(&:*2)だと、エラーが出ます。

SyntaxError: unexpected tINTEGER, expecting ')'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&:シンボル`はインスタンスメソッドを呼び出すProcオブジェクトを返す`to_proc`を呼び出すが、 (つまり`&:*2.to_proc`)
まず、`:*2` がシンボルとして解釈しようとして失敗する。
エラーメッセージはそのためだと思われます。
それで、`:"*2"`としてみたらシンボルとしては有効ですが、
 `*2`というメソッドが`Integer`にないので失敗する。

代替として

```
mul = -> x, y { x * y }
arr2 = [1,1].map(&mul.curry.(2))
```

ではどうでしょう？

Comment: たしかに動きました！が、2行目が読めません。
よかったら解説お願いします。

Comment: カリー化というやつです。関数の一部の引数を渡した状態の関数を作ります。

Comment: [Proc#curry](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/method/Proc/i/curry.html)

Comment: なるほとです！ありがとうございます！